# How should i exclude all node_modules in electron-packager

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, electron-packager, asar

I'm using electron-packager for creating an electron.exe of my app. I need to exclude all node modules . I tried the following

```
--ignore=node_modules
```

The above is not working. Any idea how to exclude all folders/ remove node modules in final build.

Comment: I recommend using either electron-forge https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-forge or electron-builder https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder to make your life easy. Unless you have a very special use case those packages will make things easier and faster.

Comment: I highly discourage the use of electron-forge because the dependencies to electron-compile and electron-packer. Both are very flawed especially electron-compile (outated transpilers, flawed path handling for scss and the list goes on).

electron-builder on the other hand is the right tool, it will exclude all devDependencies from the "release" node modules.

Comment: `electron-forge` uses `electron-packager` to do its packaging anyway

Answer (score 21):

If you install modules as `devDependencies`, they will all be pruned automatically before packaging.

If you're using `electron-builder` you can define glob patterns as [`files`](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents) in the config. In this case `!**/node_modules/*` will exclude all of `node_modules`.

If you're using `electron-packager` you can use the [`ignore`](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#ignore) option and regular expression to exclude files.

Comment: I had to use `!node_modules/**/*`.